Удаление первых N строк файла.txt
Как удалить первые N строк файла? Порядок строк после удаления не важен.
Самый очевидный вариант для меня - посчитать в цикле количество строк, затем запустить второй цикл на удаление. Есть более чистые решения?
Для общего понимания:
Файл будет содержать максимум 50 (условно) строк из заголовков (резлуьтат парсинга). При достижении им этого количества, надо удалить первые 40, чтобы в файле остались только последние 10.
Парсер проверяет есть ли заголовок статьи в файле, если нет, то заголовок включается в результат (показывается пользователю). Если есть - игнорируется. Решение которое я ищу должно предотвратить разрастание файла.
Может есть другое решение? Типа записывать новую строку в начало, а последнюю удалять. Подскажите как правильнее, пожалуйста.

Если это не в памяти, а в файле, то если длины строк не фиксированы, то вам придётся каждый раз заново весь файл перезаписывать, сэкономить тут ничего не удастся. Вообще если у вас постоянное добавление/удаление сущностей, то проще завести какую-то БД для этого.

@CrazyElf ну файл по сути небольшой. Может быть сделать отдельный скрипт, который раз в сутки очищает файл до последних N записей.
Просто в таком формате мне удобнее с файлом работать, я смогу его json сделать, если захочу хранить больше чем один только заголовок.

Ну кстати да. Сделайте json, там список. Читаете из файла json, получаете список. Из списка вырезаете срезами что нужно. Сохраняете обратно в json.

@CrazyElf вот, звучит убедительно)) спасибо

def remove_first_n_lines(file_path, n):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(lines[n:])

# Пример использования
file_path = 'your_file.txt'
n = 5  # Количество строк для удаления
remove_first_n_lines(file_path, n)

